# How to get averages for the values in a dict which match the keys and output that to another dict

Tags: python, dictionary, average

If I have two dicts using the same keys can I add the get an output dict which has averages of the keys of the input dicts?

**Code**

```
a1_up = {"190": 34.2 , "200":44.4 , "210": 41.7 }

a1_down = {"210": 38.3 , "200" : 45.6 , "190": 35.8}
```

**Desired output**

```
out = {"190": 35.0 , "200":45.0 , "210": 40.0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
out = {}
for key, value in a1_up.iteritems():
    out[key] = (value + a1_down[key])/2
```

You will be getting the average of the 2 dictionary and add it to your new Dictionary

Comment: Thanks Mario. For Python 3 I had to change iteritems() to items() but then works perfectly.